# add base clause to a recursive predicate prolog

Tags: prolog, infinite-loop

i have a recursive predicate that is getting stuck in an infinite loop and crashes the program. the predicate that appears to be stuck in the loop is as follows

```
parts(sentence(_,VP), P) :-
   parts(VP, P).
parts(vp(V), P) :- parts(V, P).
parts(vp(verb(V), np,( np2,( np2(noun(N)))), [likes(V), what(N)])).
```

i am inputing `R = sentence(np(np(det(an), np2(adj(old), np2(noun(father))))), vp(vp(verb(likes), np(det(a), np2(adj(good), np2(noun(book)))))))` to get the output `verb(likes)` and `noun(book)`

i have read on some pages that i might need to add a base case to the loop to prevent it form going on forever, however i am unsure on how to implement one to the code.

i was just wandering how i would go about doing it to this predicate? is there a `end` function that i could add to a counter that would end the function and move to the next step?

Comment: What is the simplest case? In other words, what does the most atomic `V`, `VP` or `P` look like? That would be your base case. Do you have any basic facts to support your sentence structure? I would think you would have facts representing nouns, verbs, etc.

Comment: I don't think your infinite loop is in this code, unless you have a `Y = sentence(_, Y)` structure or a `V = vp(V)` structure.

Comment: If you want help with one of your questions, you really need to supply enough of the program and how you are calling it that we stand a chance to debug it ourselves. This kind of question is impossible for anyone to answer, because we can't even see the problem ourselves.

Comment: @DanielLyons: I think it's sufficient any call `parts(U,_)` where `var(U)`, not necessarily a cyclic structure. So a simple typo (by OP) is likely.

Comment: @CapelliC Until OP adds more information, all we can do is guess.

Comment: i ran the program in trace mode and tested each part of my whole predicate function, and this was the section it got to before getting stuck in the loop.